# How can I SUM values in a joined table without screwing up totals of values in the first table?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'd like to `SELECT` a count of the number of customers, the sum of customer order totals, and a count of customers in specific states.

I know how to do this in two queries easily, however  the same `WHERE` constraints will be used, so it seems like it would be better to do it in one query and avoid repetition. I'm eager to improve my SQL but I can't work out how to combine them. Having them as two separate queries *feels* very clumsy.

Is there a way to combine them? What factors should I consider to determine if combining them is a good idea?

---

`Customers` Table

```
*-------------*-------------*--------------*------------*
| ID_Customer | ID_State    | Name         |  ...etc... |
*-------------*-------------*--------------*------------*
```

`States` Table

```
*-------------*-------------*
| ID_State    | Name        |
*-------------*-------------*
```

`Orders` Table

```
*----------*-------------*--------------*------------*
| ID_Order | ID_Customer |   ...etc...  | Total      |
*----------*-------------*--------------*------------*
```

---

**Query 1.1 - Select Count of Customers and Count of Customers in specific states**

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS Customers, 
SUM(States.Name = 'California') AS California_Customers, 
SUM(States.Name = 'New York') AS NewYork_Customers 

FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN States ON Customers.ID_State = States.ID_State
```

**Query 1.2 - Select Sum of Customer Order Totals**

```
SELECT 
SUM(Total) AS SumOfOrderTotals

FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.ID_Customer = Orders.ID_Customer
```

---

**Query 2 - An attempt at combining the queries into one (does not work)**

```
SELECT 
COUNT (DISTINCT(Customers.ID_Customer)) AS Customers, 
SUM (Orders.Total) AS SumOfOrderTotals, 
SUM (States.Name = 'California') AS California_Customers, 
SUM (States.Name = 'New York') AS NewYork_Customers 

FROM 
Customers 
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.ID_Customer = Orders.ID_Customer 
INNER JOIN States ON Customers.ID_State = States.ID_State
```

Obviously this does not work as it is because the `INNER JOIN` between `Customers` and `Orders` means that `States.Name`s are counted x*N* (where *N* is the number of orders a customer has) for each customer, making those totals wrong.

---

I considered a Subquery, however I'm not sure how to apply one in this case (if that is what I should be doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the aggregation before the `join` or use subqueries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(c.ID_Customer)) AS Customers, 
       o.SumOfOrderTotals, 
       SUM(s.Name = 'California') AS California_Customers, 
       SUM(s.Name = 'New York') AS NewYork_Customers 
FROM Customers c JOIN
     States s
     ON c.ID_State = s.ID_State CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(Total) as SumOfOrderTotals
      FROM Orders o
     ) o;
```

You could also write this as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(c.ID_Customer)) AS Customers, 
       (SELECT SUM(Total)
        FROM Orders o
       ) as SumOfOrderTotals, 
       SUM(s.Name = 'California') AS California_Customers, 
       SUM(s.Name = 'New York') AS NewYork_Customers 
FROM Customers c JOIN
     States s
     ON c.ID_State = s.ID_State;
```

Comment: Thank you! The latter was along the lines of what I had in mind, but I wasn't sure how and where to fit a subquery in.

Comment: I'm getting the error '#2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' on the second query. If I remove the subquery it works fine. Is use of a subquery in a `SELECT` statement definitely allowable?

Comment: @Eilidh . . . Ooops, I had left a `group by` in (originally I thought you wanted the totals by customers).

Comment: Nope! I was wondering why that was there, I was a little confused by its presence :)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly (and obviously the `WHERE` clause is essentially added twice, in the subquery for the `SUM` and the outer query) - Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You place the subquery where you would have placed any additional field, as another thing in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS Customers, 
  SUM(States.Name = 'California') AS California_Customers, 
  SUM(States.Name = 'New York') AS NewYork_Customers,
  (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM Orders) AS SumOfOrderTotals
FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN States ON Customers.ID_State = States.ID_State;
```

Comment: I tried this (well, the latter version in the other answer) however I receive the error '#2014 Commands out of sync, you can't run this command now' - if I remove the subquery it works okay.

Comment: Well, let's see. Gordon counts distinct customer IDs, which is the same as Count(\*). Okay. But that GROUP BY in his sub-select makes no sense. One has to select *one* value.

Comment: Thanks - I did stare at it for quite a while wondering what it was all about - guess now I know ;)